# Best PHP search technique for heavy database like apache solr for java

Tags: php, mysql, solr, jvm, advanced-search

I have used apache solr in my java project smoothly, but when i come to the end to solve a same kind of issue with PHP, this issue is arising:

To run apache SOLR, we need JVM to be installed on the server. But I don't know whether there is JVM installed in my client server or not. Because it is PHP apache linux server (not dedicated), I don't know whether I will get to access the console by which I can manage a bit.

Could any body tell me what is the alternative for apache solr for simple PHP environment?
Or please suggest me best indexing search technique for PHP.

Comment: There is a PHP implementation of Lucene, or hosted Solr services.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. The worst solution, but probably the easiest if you want to remain in this (shared?) environment is to use a php solution like aitchnyu suggested. You could even use your own.
2. Shared environments often have access to mysql, you could search [based off that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). (Also not ideal, but possible)
3. Upgrade servers to like a virtual-shared server or use a seperate server for SOLR (I use ec2 free-tier which works well)

Not really an option but to answer your question, yes you can access the [terminal through php](https://github.com/spyrosoft/PHP-Terminal-Emulator) but this is far from what you should really do because most shared servers disable access through php (in fact they didn't give you ssh access for a reason).

Also because even if they forgot to close this security hole (which happens sometimes) you will exhaust your resources (ram, cpu) pretty quick and you'll have to upgrade servers anyway.